# How correct calculate the probabilities of violation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have a task. Calculate the probability of a train driver’s violation.
How i decide it.

```
1. I calculate how many the driver made trips during the period of his work (I took 2 years) (2230)
2. Then i calculate how many time he violated the rule(200)
3. Then i divide number of violations of the rule on number of trips
200/2230=0,089.
```

Is this way correct to calculate the probabilities of violation or not?
Cause can be cases when he can violate the rule many time in one trip and proportion can be (fake example) 200/100=200% of propability.
If my way to decide task is wrong, how should i calculate  the probabilities of violation?
(ideally example on R)

Comment: https://www.statstodo.com/Poisson_Exp.php - I think this one wil lbe helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Poisson distribution, which describes the probability of the number of recurrent event that may happen for a defined time interval.

But the limit is that:

1. K is 0, 1, 2...and your probability is 0,089 which means the time interval is quite large.
2. The events (violation) are probability not independent of each other, because the driver could try to be careful next time if he violates.